# boost module in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, boost, module

I am trying to debug a file for a project I am working on, and the first thing I made sure to do is install/build all of the modules that the file is importing. Thisis the first line of the file:

```
from scitbx.array_family import flex
```

which in turn reads from flex.py,

```
from __future__ import division
import boost.optional # import dependency
import boost.std_pair # import dependency
import boost.python
```

I entered the commands in ipython individually and get stuck on importing boost.optional. Since they are all from the same module I tried searching for the module named boost.

I found the site: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

and installed the related .bz2 file in the same directory as my other modules to make sure it is within **sys.path**. However I still can't get ipython to import anything. Am I completely off base in my approach or is there some other boost module that I can't find? I should mention that I am a complete novice with computers, and am learning as I go along. Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you have installed is called [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).  This is a collection of C++ libraries, one of which is [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/index.html).  However this library doesn't provide Python modules that you can import directly - it doesn't provide `boost.optional`.  Instead it enables interoperability between Python and C++ - you can write a C++ library using Boost.Python that can then be used in a normal Python interpreter.

In you case `boost.optional` is provided by the [CCTBX](http://cci.lbl.gov/cctbx_docs/index.html#) collection of software, which does depend on Boost and Boost.Python.  So you are not too far off.  [This thread](http://phenix-online.org/pipermail/cctbxbb/2014-June/000932.html) in the mailing list covers your error message and some potential solutions.

Essentially you need to use the custom `cctbx.python` command (or `scitbx.python`, they are equivalent) to run python as this sets the `PYTHONPATH` correctly for their requirements.  It's also documented on [this page](http://cctbx.sourceforge.net/current/installation.html).

Comment: Hi @markstreatfield, That makes sense to do it this way, but when I am in the directory of the file I want to run, I enter the following and this is the output:                                      $    cctbx.python optimizer.py 
    -bash: cctbx.python: command not found'

Comment: nevermind, the installation instructions helped me figure out one step that I overlooked, and then using the cctbx.python command works as expected! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.  I imagine the `command not found` is because `cctbx.python` is not in the `PATH` environment variable.